# Вычеркивание элементов списка на jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Решил попробовать сделать простую todoшку для самообучения. Столкнулся с такой проблемой - элементы списка имеют одинаковый класс или id. Из за чего в первом случае при вычеркивании одного элемента вычёркиваются все, а во втором вычёркивается только первый.

https://jsfiddle.net/brachkoff/1gpo2hr3/4/ - вариант с id

```
$('#task__checkbox').click(function() {
  if ($('#task__checkbox').prop('checked') == true) {
    $('#task__text').css('text-decoration', 'line-through')
  }

  if ($('#task__checkbox').prop('checked') == false) {
    $('#task__text').css('text-decoration', 'none')
  }
})
```

Как сделать так чтобы все работало нормально, при этом не создавая отдельный id для каждого элемента списка?

Comment: Дополню. Нужно использовать this, чтобы работать с тем элементом, который вызвал функцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#list').on('click', '.task__checkbox', function() {
  $(this).closest(".task").find('.task__text').
    css('text-decoration', this.checked ? 'line-through' : 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="todo">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>ToDo</h1>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <ul id="list">
    <li class="task">
     <input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox">
     <span class="task__text" contenteditable="true">Тут еще что то</span>
    </li>
    <li class="task">
      <input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox">
      <span class="task__text" contenteditable="true">Еще какие то буквы</span>
    </li>
    <li class="task">
      <input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox">
      <span class="task__text" contenteditable="true">Слова слова слова</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш решение перестает работать если после загрузки страницы добавляются еще пункты списка (так как это todo это важно)

Answer (score 1):

Такие вещи без `js` делаются. 
P.S. одинаковых `id` на странице быть не должно.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('body').append('<label><input type="checkbox"><span>new task</span></label>');
})
```

```css
label{
  display:block;
  margin:0 0 .5em;
}
label :checked + span{
  text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Добавить еще</button>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>lorem ispum dolor</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>lorem ispum dolor</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>lorem ispum dolor</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>lorem ispum dolor</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Да, но в данном случае мне было интересно решение именно на js + jq.